# Fleiss-kappa score for interannotator agreement

Tags: cohens-kappa, agreement-statistics

In my dataset I have a set of categories, where for every category I have a set of 150 examples. Each example has been annotated as true/false by 5 human raters. I am computing the inter-annotator agreement using the Fleiss-kappa score:

```
1) for the entire dataset

2) for each category in particular
```

However, the results I obtained show that the Fleiss-kappa score for the entire dataset does not equal the average of the Fleiss-kappa score for each category. In my computation I am using a standard built-in package to compute the scores. Could this be due to a bug in my matrix computation, or are the scores not supposed to be equal? Thanks!